# Maintain dependency object instance within the thread

Tags: asynchronous, dependencies, task, autofac

Need help on below issue, I have below method:

```
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    Task.Run(() => DoTheStuff())
    Return Ok()
}
```

**Note:** Here I don't want to use `async/await` keyword, as I don't care about the result of `DoTheStuff()` method. I just need to open one thread and execute the code.

`DoTheStuff()` method refers the objects which are injected through dependency injection (Autofac). and in Module.Config I have registered all the required dependencies with lifetimescope.

Below issue I am facing call to `Task.Run(() => DoTheStuff())` starts new thread executing `DoTheStuff()` method.
At the same time `Test()` method completes it execution with return `Ok()`, but `DoTheStuff` method  is still running asynchronously.

With execution of `Test()` method, the registered dependencies gets disposed, and `DoTheStuff()` method throws below exception:

> Nested lifetime cannot be created from the LifetimeScope as it has
>   already been disposed

Can someone please let me know how to maintain dependency object instance within the thread?

Comment: Please provide code with registrations of the dependencies. And please say, if `Test` method belong to controller?

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple options.

1. Extract `DoTheStuff` into its own service. Register the services that you're injecting and using in `DoTheStuff` as `InstancePerDependency` so that the service gets its own instance. See https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html.
2. Add a `Wait`:

   ```
   var t = Task.Run(() => DoTheStuff());
   t.Wait();
   return Ok();
   ```

Let me know if neither of those works.